# How to update state inside componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using fetch API and I want update the const called state inside the componentDidMount() (with onChange) which are being using in a template string. How do I update this value with onChange?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Data extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: {},
            value: '',
            isLoaded: false
        }
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        const state = this.state.value

        fetch(`http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=J9X3EOT2EM8U&format=json&by=zone&zone=${state}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json,
            })
        });
    }


    render(){
        const {isLoaded} = this.state;

        if(!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option value="America/Chicago">Chicago</option>
                    <option value="America/Sao_Paulo">São Paulo</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So, how can I update the value of the const state with onChange?

Comment: When component mounts, `this.state.value` will be an empty string (which you set in your constructor). Not entirely sure what you're asking here?

Comment: @EvilGeniusJamie I want to send the value of option selected to the const inside componentDidMount()

 for example, when I select chicago the fetch API link will be:
https://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=J9X3EOT2EM8U&format=json&by=zone&zone=America/Chicago

and when I select São Paulo the link will be: 
https://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=J9X3EOT2EM8U&format=json&by=zone&zone=America/Sao_Paulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` is called when the React component has mounted, and it happens only once.

If I understand correctly, you want to call `fetch` on each change of the value stored under `value` state property, so the `componentDidMount` method is not a perfect place to put that kind of logic. You can create a separate method called `fetchData` and pass the value to it as an argument. Then you can call that method on `componentDidMount` as well as on each value property change (in our case - `onChange` event).

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Data extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: {},
      value: "America/Chicago",
      isLoaded: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { value } = this.state;

    this.fetchData(value);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      value
    });

    this.fetchData(value);
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoaded, value, items } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange} value={value}>
          <option value="America/Chicago">Chicago</option>
          <option value="America/Sao_Paulo">São Paulo</option>
        </select>
        {JSON.stringify(items)}
      </div>
    );
  }

  fetchData(value) {
    fetch(
      `https://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=J9X3EOT2EM8U&format=json&by=zone&zone=${value}`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json
        });
      });
  }
}
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/728jnjprmq

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's not work here, the code doest return for example "https://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=J9X3EOT2EM8U&format=json&by=zone&zone=America/Sao_Paulo" when I select "São Paulo". May I wasn't clear about my problem!

Comment: @Henrique I'm not sure we're understanding each other correctly but let me try help you :) In your example, you are sending a request to timezonedb api but the zone query parameter is set to empty string, right? That's because in the constructor you initialise state with `value` property of value `''`. What is the issue you are experiencing in my answer?

Comment: I'm gonna try, sorry if this still confused :). The value that I expects is: When I select for example the option called "Chicago" my parameter called value change from empty to "America/Chicago" (which is the value inside de option chicago). And this value is passed to my const called "value" inside componentDidMount() and then that const called "value" change the URL which have the template string ${value}. then the  URL inside Fetch will be "http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=J9X3EOT2EM8U&format=json&by=zone&zone=America/Chicago"

Comment: @Henrique I'm sorry, but that's not possible because of the React's architecture. The `value` property of the state is changing as you want (in both yours and my examples), however, after the component is once mounted, `componentDidMount` *will not* be called again because it is intended to be called only once when the component mounts into the DOM. Please take a look at my code and how the data flow looks like - I think we're talking about the same result :)

Comment: I've checked your code again and thank you, it worked perfectly as I expected. Beside that, thank you for your explication, now I'm gonna study yout code, thank you again Tomasz :)

Comment: If you want anything more, please DM or mention me :)

Answer (score 0):

Tomasz's code has 2 mistakes: (1) it fetches resources w/o checking if the component has been unmounted; (2) it starts the request w/o updating the UI first.

I would do the following instead:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Data extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: {},
            value: '',
            isLoaded: false
        }

        this._isMounted = false;

        // don't forget to bind your methods
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        const value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ value }, () => {
            if (!this._isMounted) return;
            const url = `http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=J9X3EOT2EM8U&format=json&by=zone&zone=${value}`
            fetch(url).then((res) => {
                if (!this._isMounted) return;
                const data = res.json();
                this.setState({ isLoaded: true, items: data });
            })
        });
    }

    render(){
        const { isLoaded } = this.state;

        if(!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option value="America/Chicago">Chicago</option>
                    <option value="America/Sao_Paulo">São Paulo</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @neuber for some reason isLoaded is always "false" and doesn't change into "true"

Comment: @Henrique my mistake. Check the updated value for `const url` - I did not change `state` for `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to refresh the value of `this.state.items` when the user changes the value of the `select`, you can do this in the `onChange`. However, your code is in a few (incorrect) pieces. Let's start from the top.

First of all, you're setting the `value` property of `state` to `''`, so your `componentDidMount` function is going to see that value. I assume that's no good, so let's strip that out of `componentDidMount` entirely. We can move this code to the `handleChange` function instead, but it'll still need to be changed:

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});

    fetch(`http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=J9X3EOT2EM8U&format=json&by=zone&zone=${e.target.value}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: json,
        })
    });
}
```

Notice my change - we can't access the value from the state, because `setState` is asynchronous, and so the value hasn't been updated by this point. We know the value comes from the `select` though.

The other thing you could do to improve this functionality is to turn the `select` into a controlled component. To do this, you just have to set the value of the field to be controlled by the state of this component. Since you're using an `onChange` listener for this, it makes the field a controlled component (if you weren't using an onChange, it would be a read-only field.

The `loading` variable in `state` appears to be being used incorrectly, I'm guessing you just need to check if there's data in 'items'. I'll remove this for now, but you could come back to this.

```
render(){
    const {isLoaded} = this.state;

    if(!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="America/Chicago">Chicago</option>
                <option value="America/Sao_Paulo">São Paulo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```